# Finding the volume between sphere and hyperboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, cylindrical-coordinates

I am trying to find the volume between the sphere: $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ and the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$. I set the integral as: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{\sqrt{1+z^2}}^{\sqrt{9-z^2}}rdrdzd\theta$$ but it does not give me the correct answer. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my calculations?

Comment: Draw a sketch (say of a typical cross-section containing the $z$-axis). Think about your $z$ limits.

Comment: I think z goes up to 3 and -3 since the outer shape is a sphere with raidus 3. Am i thinking wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are thinking wrong. Did you draw the sketch as I suggested? Look at it.

Comment: I guess they intersect at 2 and -2, but I still cant see how z does not go up to 3.

Comment: Because when $2\le |z|\le 3$, you can be inside the sphere, but how are you between the hyperboloid and the sphere?

Comment: I am trying to find the volume of the hyperboloid between the z values of -2 and 2 and I am also looking for the volume of the sphere between the z values of 2 and 3 and also -2 and -3.  Basically the section under the sphere and over the hyperboloid.

Comment: No, you are not following directions. Between the sphere and the hyperboloid (of one sheet, not two) means *outside* the hyperboloid and *inside* the sphere. Pictures, pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parametrization of the solid is wrong. Notice that $\sqrt{z^2+1}<\sqrt{9-z^2}$ when $-2<z< 2$, but $\sqrt{z^2+1}>\sqrt{9-z^2}$ when $|z|>2$.

When $-2\leq z\leq 2$, the part of the solid looks like [a pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid#/media/File:Hyperboloid1.png) and it is parametrized as $-2\leq z\leq 2$, $0\leq r\leq\sqrt{z^2+1}$, $0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$. We can find the volume of this part by cross-section method: $V_1=\int_{-2}^2A(z)dz=2\int_0^2\pi r^2dz=2\pi\int_0^2(z^2+1)dz=\frac{28}3\pi$.

When $2\leq z\leq 3$, the part of the solid is a spherical cap parametrized by $2\leq z\leq\sqrt{9-r^2}$, $0\leq r\leq\sqrt 5$, $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$. Hence, its volume is $V_2=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt5}(\sqrt{9-r^2}-2)rdrd\theta=\frac83\pi$. Bottom cap is also $V_3=\frac83\pi$. The total volume $V=V_1+V_2+V_3=\frac{28+8+8}{3}\pi=\frac{44}3\pi.$

Comment: This is incorrect, I believe. How is this “between” the two surfaces? In fact, you’re finding the complementary volume (inside the sphere) of what’s requested. Clearly the textbook should make their wording unambiguous.

Comment: Inner volume between hyperboloid and sphere:

$V_1=\int _{-2}^2\int _0^{2 \pi }\int _{\sqrt{z^2+1}}^{\sqrt{9-z^2}}\rho d\rho d\phi dz=\frac{64 \pi }{3}$

Comment: You are both right. Probably, the complement $\frac{4}{3}\pi 3^3-\frac{44}{3}\pi$ is the answer.